# Hiding dropdown of active menu item

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am trying to do something like finance.yahoo.com's menu which stops it's drop down at active menu item. I have already applied jQuery to add `addclass()` to add `.active` class but now I just want to stop my drop down at active class.

Where I tried this code but not works

```
$('#menu > ul > li > a.active').parent('div').hide();
```

Comment: inspect and check wheather your following code is working or not $('#menu > ul > li > a[href="'+url+'."]').addClass('active')

Answer (score 0):

Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) as `div` is not direct parent of `a`. closest will look first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

```
$('#menu > ul > li > a.active').closest('div').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind to `.mouseleave()` event smth. similar to

```
$('.main_menu_container').mouseleave( function () {
    $(this).children('.submenu').hide();
});
```